# How to store the number of affected records and return it as a parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an in parameter (set = 0), to keep track of the count of entries I will be modifying. I am trying to merge data into a table called Table1, the records that have been updated in a different table (Table2) since the last time Table1 has been updated. The conditional statement will compare the **Table1.LastUpdate** column to the **max(Modified_date**) column of **Table2** and only insert entries where the **table1.last_update** column is greater than the **table2.max(modified_date)** column. Then I will need to store this number and return it as an out parameter. What I have is follows:

```
create or replace procedure test_proc (rUpdated_Row_Count IN NUMBER, rUpdated_Row_Count_2 OUT NUMBER) is
CURSOR c1 is
            select max(modified_date) as max_modified_date
              from table1;
        l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
-----------
CURSOR c2 is
            select table2_id
                 , last_update
              from table2;
         k_var c2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
LOOP
Open c1;
        Fetch c1 into l_var;
Open c2;
        Fetch c2 into k_var;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
IF k_var.last_update > l_var.max_modified_date THEN 
Insert into table2(table2_id, last_update)
            values(null, k_var.last_update);
            commit;
      rUpdated_Row_Count_2 := rUpdated_Row_Count + 1;
END IF;
END LOOP;
Close c1;
Close c2;
END test_proc;
```

Thanks in advance!

Modified my code (after doing further research):

```
create or replace procedure test_proc (rUpdated_Row_Count IN NUMBER, rUpdated_Row_Count_2 OUT NUMBER) is
CURSOR c1 is
            select max(modified_date) as max_modified_date
              from table1;
        l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
-----------
CURSOR c2 is
            select table2_id
                 , last_update
              from table2;
         k_var c2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
Open c1;
Open c2;
LOOP
        Fetch c1 into l_var;
        Fetch c2 into k_var;
EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
IF k_var.last_update > l_var.max_modified_date THEN 
Insert into table2(table2_id, last_update)
            values(null, k_var.last_update);
            commit;
      rUpdated_Row_Count_2 := rUpdated_Row_Count + 1;
END IF;
END LOOP;
Close c1;
Close c2;
END test_proc;
```

Reproducable data / Code is below:

```
Create table1
(
  table1_id number,
  modified_date date
 );

Create table2
(
  table2_id number,
  last_update date
);

insert into table1(table1_id, modified_date) values(1, sysdate);
insert into table1(table1_id, modified_date) values(2, sysdate);
insert into table1(table1_id, modified_date) values(3, sysdate -1);
insert into table2(table2_id, last_update) values(1, sysdate + 1);
insert into table2(table2_id, last_update) values(2, sysdate + 2);
```

Comment: anyone? so lost... I was able to take out the parameter variables (rUpdated_Row_Count and rUpdated_Row_Count_2) and all syntax related to those variables and the code runs fine. not sure how to get this to work, any help / general direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what the "IN" parameter is for.  Also not quite sure about the overall rationale.  However, here's how I'd write a first version of your procedure:

```
create or replace procedure test_proc2 (
  rUpdated_Row_Count IN NUMBER
, rUpdated_Row_Count_2 IN OUT NUMBER ) 
is
  max_modified_date date ;
begin
  select max( modified_date ) into max_modified_date from table1 ;  

  for rec_ in ( 
     select table2_id, last_update
     from table2
  ) loop
      if rec_.last_update > max_modified_date then 
        insert into table2( table2_id, last_update )
          values( null, rec_.last_update ) ;
        rUpdated_Row_Count_2 := rUpdated_Row_Count_2 + 1 ;
      end if ;
  end loop;
end ;
/
```

Using your test tables (your DDL code should be: CREATE TABLE table1 ... by the way), we can use the following anonymous block for executing the procedure.

```
-- not sure what the "IN" parameter is used for 
declare
  rowcount_in number := 0 ;  -- not needed
  rowcount_out number := 0 ;
begin
  test_proc2( rowcount_in, rowcount_out ) ;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'updated rows: ' || rowcount_out ) ;
end;
/

updated rows: 2
```

After executing the anonymous block the tables contain ...

```
SQL> select * from table1 ;
TABLE1_ID  MODIFIED_DATE  
1          15-MAY-18      
2          15-MAY-18      
3          14-MAY-18      


SQL> select * from table2 ;
TABLE2_ID  LAST_UPDATE  
1          16-MAY-18    
2          17-MAY-18    
NULL       16-MAY-18    
NULL       17-MAY-18
```

Many people will tell you that you should use BULK operations (BULK COLLECT, FORALL etc) whenever possible.  Does all that help you?

Comment: The IN parameter is a number that denotes the number of rows that have been updated. It will be whatever number we decide to pass in.

Comment: I am trying to keep track of how many rows I've inserted. Thats what those parameters are for. Do you know how i may be able to do that? Right now, it's returning to me a value of '0'

Comment: In the IF block, there is an INSERT and an assignment ( := ).  In your original code, you are adding 1 to the "rUpdated_Row_Count", and you are storing this value in "rUpdated_Row_Count_2".  "rUpdated_Row_Count" is the one and the SAME value in each iteration!  However, this is (maybe) not easy to see.

Comment: Suggestions: {1} create a little log table, and {2} write a DEBUG version of your procedure.  Let the debug version INSERT the parameter (and variable) values into the log table.  Examine the contents of your log table carefully, so that you understand what your procedure is really doing (behind the scenes).  I have written an example - see   
 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a34ae92ca5b5f9432687bafaf0070cc  // Remember to clear out the testlog table befor the next test run.